# Parsing multiple child nodes XML in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have a XML file as follows.

```
<listings>
<list>
  <fruitlist>
   <name>Apple </name>
   <price>1$ </price>
  </fruitlist>
  <vegelist>
    <vegename>Tomato</vegename>
    <cost>2$</cost>
  <vegelist>
 </list>
 <list>
  <fruitlist>
   <name>Orange </name>
   <price>1$ </price>
  </fruitlist>
  <vegelist>
    <vegename>Potato</vegename>
    <cost>2$</cost>
  <vegelist>
 </list>
</listings>
```

how to parse the entire file which has multiple child nodes contineously in javascript.

Comment: Your xml contains errors .You have to close vegelist elements.

Answer (score 0):

Example with Javascript:

```
function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else // code for IE5 and IE6
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",filename,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}
//Open your xml file
    xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("mydemo.xml");
    document.write(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("list")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    ...
```

or, if you want to loop through your results,then try:

```
var root = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('list');
for(var i=0, i<root[0].childNodes.length,i++){
    //Action with loop results
...
}
```

This [w3schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_loadxmldoc.asp) helps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you have the possibility to use jQuery, but it would be easy with it.

For instance you could do stuff like :

```
$(xml).find("vegename").each(function(index,vegename){

     console.log( $(vegename).text() ) // Will give you "Tomato" and "Potato"

})
```

There are many tutorials out there for parsing with jQuery.